# Get data from user test on device to mac

Tags: ios, xcode, plist, transfer

I'm doing some user tests of my new iOS app and store some test data in a plist. When I do that in the simulator it is easy to get that file for further analysis on my mac, but how can I easily get it from a real device? This will only be used during testing and will not be part of the final version.

Possible ways I have read about but not tried (in hope to get some directions here first):

- E-mail attachment
- Enable file transfer to iTunes
- Jailbreak (but don't want to)

Currently what I am doing is to NSLog it and copy and paste from Xcode into Excel, but this requires that the device is tethered to my mac.

Any experience or advice on easiest way to get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save data from Organizer. Just click on your device and it'll show in right pane. Files from documents folder and possibly other folders can be saved.

Comment: Hi TheBlack. On Xcode 4 I can go to Organizer, click on my device, select Applications and then download the whole directory structure for that App. Exactly what I needed. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes use iPhone Explorer to do this, because the plist file I want is not in my Documents folder.  I use it to navigate to the files associated with my app on the device.  Just connect your device to your laptop, run iPhone Explorer and then use it to locate the plist file you want and drag and drop it wherever you want.